# Broken auto-mute after 12.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa

Speakers stay on in Ubuntu 12.04 when headphones are plugged into the jack. (Fujitsu T2010, ICH8 chipset, ALC262 audio). All was working fine in 11.10. /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf contains `options snd-hda-intel model=fujitsu` which used to be working before.

I submitted a bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/997420), but in the meantime I am looking for an acceptable solution.  Right now I can't use my laptop to listen to music or watch videos in public places, which is very frustrating.

Is there *some* workaround that will allow to mute the speakers while listening to the headphone output?

Comment: Type "alsamixer" (without quotes) in terminal. Is Auto-Mute Mode enabled? I've been dealing with no sound coming from the front panel headphone jack. My issue has another fix entirely, but I've been across quite a few other answered questions that recommend checking the alsamixer settings.

Comment: Alsamixer doesn't have anything related to auto-mute.  That's part of the problem.

Comment: try finding a setting for auto mute in kmix or gnome's equivalent. I remember fixing it by checking a box there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by:

1. entering **alsamixer** in **Terminal**, and
2. moving to **Auto-Mute** setting in **Playback** View, and
3. changing it via **Up/Down Arrow** from **Disabled** to **Speaker**

(thanks to answers by **user6388**9 and **Ivan** in the comments)